# Initialization of 2D array with dynamic number of rows and fixed number of columns. C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, fixed, dynamic-arrays

I'm having problem with creating my 2D dynamic array in C++. I want it to have dynamic number (e.g. numR) of "rows" and fixed (e.g. 2) number of "columns".

I tried doing it like this:

```
const numC = 2;
int numR;
numR = 10;
double *myArray[numC];
myArray = new double[numR];
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Is it possible to do it in such a way?

Of course I could use `double **myArray` and initialize it as if both dimensions are dynamic (with numC used as limiter in loop) but I would like to avoid it if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? What is `threadAccelerationTable` and how does it relate to `myArray`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to do it in such a way?

Yes:

```
double (*myArray)[numC] = new double[numR][numC];
// ...
delete[] myArray;
```

This may look a little unusual, but 5.3.4 §5 clearly states:

> the type of `new int[i][10]` is `int (*)[10]`

Note that many programmers are not familiar with C declarator syntax and will not understand this code. Also, manual dynamic allocation is not exception safe. For these reaons, a vector of arrays is better:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

std::vector<std::array<double, numC> > vec(numR);
// ...
// no manual cleanup necessary
```

Replace `std::array` with `std::tr1::array` or `boost::array`, depending on your compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a [std::vector](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/container/vector/start), and take advantage of its [constructor](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/container/vector/vector):

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > my2Darray(2, std::vector<int>(10));
my2Darray[0][0] = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be a loop since you need to create an array *for every column*.

I think what you're after is:

```
double *myArray[numC];
for (int i = 0; i < numC; i++) {
    myArray[i] = new double[numR];
}

// some code...

// Cleanup:
for (int i = 0; i < numC; i++) {
    delete [] myArray[i];
}
```

This declares an array of pointers (to `double`) with `numC` elements, then creates an array of `double`s with `numR` elements for each column in `myArray`. Don't forget to release the memory when you're done with it or you'll have memory leaks.

Comment: You don't need a loop, see my answer. (I did not downvote BTW.)

Comment: That's C declarator syntax for ya :)

Answer (score -1):

Your indexes should be row, then column.

```
double** myArray = new double*[numR];
for( unsigned int i = 0; i < numR; i++ ) {
    myArray[i] = new double[numC];
}
```

Access row 2, column 5:

```
myArray[2][5];
```

Comment: It really doesn't matter which comes first, as long as he's consistent about indexing them in the same order.

Comment: You don't need a loop, see my answer. (I did not downvote BTW.)